# Correct File Path within C# Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, relative-path, filepath

Can someone please tell me how I can get the correct file path for the file data.xml? Here is where the file sits:

[image]

Here is my C# code that is checking to see if the file exists for the supplied path:

```
public class Parser
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("App_Data/data.xml"));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I keep getting False, meaning such a file does not exist. So file paths I've tried so far include:

```
"~/App_Data/data.xml"
"/App_Data/data.xml"
"App_Data/data.xml"
```

If this was a Web application, I would know what to do, by using the HttpContext and getting at the file. But since this is a Console application, I don't know.

On a related note, what is the difference between a Console application and an Executable application? Am I correct that there is no difference, since a Console App can be an Executable app if it has a Main method?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can also add data.xml to your output build directory. You will need to right click on the file and select `Copy if newer` or `Copy always` for the `Copy to output directory option`.

Then you can use the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("App_Data/data.xml")); // Should print True
```

However, if you expect data.xml to change then just point to the full path, somewhere outside your project (assuming App_Data/data.xml is copied to C:/Temp) then:

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("C:/Temp/App_Data/data.xml")); // Prints True
```

Also, for your other question related to a console and an executable application, the exe can be a different application type such as console or wpf or winforms (that's the way visual studio groups these).

Comment: I just did, and ran it again, and still got a False :(

Comment: Is the Build Action set to Content?

Comment: You got an up vote for clarifying the executable application bit. Yep I have it set to Content and Copy Always.

Comment: Try rebuilding your project from the Visual Studio menu. I've just run the code and it works for me in debug and release mode. You should see an App_Data directory with data.xml there if you navigate to your project path and look into bin/Debug folder

Comment: Ha silly me. For your suggestion, I was putting a forward slash in front like so `"/App_Data/data.xml"` removing the slash has made it return True. Thank You. Before I mark yours as Answer. What are the pit falls (if any) of doing it like this. **This executable application will be running once a day to parse XML data and store it in a database**. Do you see any possible pitfalls with your answer, now that you know a bit more about the overall project? Thanks

Comment: Well it depends. If you expect data.xml to be that file then my answer isn't what you want. Adding that file or any resource for that matter in the way I suggested will embed that as part of your exe. It may be better to have this file somewhere outside the project and reference the full path to the file instead

Comment: Good thing I clarified things a bit more. :) Do you know how I can get it to return True when the file will be sitting anywhere else on the Hard Drive?

Answer (score 18):

Get the current working directory:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/App_Data/data.xml";
```

Important: `App_Data` has to be in the same directory as your application is.

The best way to get your `data.xml` file is to carry it with your application or to save it e.g. in the "home" directory of your user (or whatever it is called under Windows 8).

Comment: Well I am within Visual Studio 2012, and that is where I press the F5 button to run my app. So all project files will sit in C:/Users/Me/My Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/XML Parser/XML Parser .. etc You know, the default place where projects go in VS.

Comment: As far as I know the application is built and put into the build\release directory or sth.; open up a commandline and navigate through your application directory and check where the .exe and where the `App_Data` directory are located.

Comment: Here is where the [App_Data folder is](https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/713/filepath.jpg).

Comment: Copy the file from bin to the XML Parser or copy the App_Data dir to bin and run it.

Comment: Really it is good answer if we combine it with @Leon 's answer. Where Leon has mentioned to change "Copy to Output directory" property for files which are inside App_Data folder

Comment: its getting path from debug folder. i think its wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the file and use reflection to get it.

```
Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("file name");
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
steamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
d.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
r.Close();
```

Check this article out. It shows how to embed and get a file using reflection:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netframework-4.8